# Best way to output array from controller to view in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

I currently have this in my view to output data from an array that comes from my controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  @foreach ($details as $detail)
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ $detail->name }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>in view</h1>

      {{ $detail->name }}
      <br>
      {{ $detail->street }}
      <br>
      {{ $detail->city }}, {{ $detail->state }}. {{ $detail->zip }}


  </body>
    @endforeach
</html>
```

This is the function in my controller:

```
  $details = DB::table('restaurants')->where('id', $restaurant_id)->get();
  return view ('restaurant.detail')->with('details', $details);
```

My question is: is there a better way to do this? I tried using the blade syntax without the @foreach and didn't have any luck.

I don't want to output this multiple times, the only reason I have the foreach there is because it is the only way I could get it to output.

If this is how it is supposed to work, no worries, I am just not familiar enough yet with blade to know if there is a better way to output this.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldnt be recreating entire HTML documents. What is it exactly you want?

Comment: @ImAtWar  first I had the foreach in just the body, but I wanted to be able to output the $detail->name in the <title>, therefore I just wrapped it around the full HTML doc to get that to work. I want to be able to output this array, but it only works with the foreach. Is there a way where I won't need that?

Comment: Having the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` elements inside a loop looks very wrong. A browser will probably only render one `<html>` document and ignore any subsequent ones.

Comment: @apokryfos correct. It will work if I move the foreach (fixed above), but is there a way to output the array without the need for the foreach loop?

Comment: @Ddrossi93 technically speaking, no. However you can use one of the many functions that does the looping for you like e.g. `$details->each(function ($detail) { /* do stuff */ });`

Comment: @apokryfos gotcha. Thank you. Would it be better for me to make each an individual variable in the controller then pass it to the view?

Comment: Well it depends what you need really. If you only need one specific detail then you can change your controller query to `DB::table("restaurants")->where("id",$restaurant_id)->first()` which only returns one entry. If `id` is unique for that table (which it probably is) then there would only be 0 or 1 restaurant with that id anyway. However I highly recommend you look into [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent).

Comment: @apokryfos that worked perfectly! Got rid of the foreach as well! If you wanna put that as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be selecting something by id, so that's probably unique. When you do `->get()` by default it will return a collection of results because it assumes there's always a chance that there's more than 1. When selecting by ID however you know if something exists by that id, there's only going to be 1 of it. You can change the code to:

```
$detail = DB::table('restaurants')->where('id', $restaurant_id)->first();
return view ('restaurant.detail')->with('detail', $detail);
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ $detail->name }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>in view</h1>

      {{ $detail->name }}
      <br>
      {{ $detail->street }}
      <br>
      {{ $detail->city }}, {{ $detail->state }}. {{ $detail->zip }}


  </body>
</html>
```

I highly recommend you look into [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Example of an eloquent model:

```
class Restaurant extends Model {} //The table name for model "Restaurant" is assumed to be restaurants
```

Then you can find a single restaurant:

```
$detail = Restaurant::find($restaurant_id);
```

Comment: Thanks again. I'll start digging more into Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want multiple `title` tags in your page ? It doesn't make any sense.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><!-- What do you want to show here ? --></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>in view</h1>
        @foreach ($details as $detail)
            {{ $detail->name }}
            <br>
            {{ $detail->street }}
            <br>
            {{ $detail->city }}, {{ $detail->state }}. {{ $detail->zip}}
        @endforeach
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want multiple title tags. The $detail->name will not work unless it is within the foreach loop. That is my question. Is there a way to do it without the foreach

Comment: Is there always one element in your array ?

Comment: In your controller just put `$detail = details[0]` or `$detail = current(details)`. Pass `$detail` to your view then in your view simply do `$detail->name`.

Comment: If there are two elements in your array wich one do you want to show in your `title` tag ?

Comment: I added the code from my controller function above to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by below methods,
1. Use `first()` to retrieve single record like below,

```
// Controller Code
$detail = DB::table('restaurants')->where('id', $restaurant_id)->first();

<!-- View Code -->
<title>{{ $detail->name }}</title>
```

2. Use `find()` to retrieve single record by its primary key like below. It works similar to `first()` but it retrieves data by its primary key.

```
// Controller Code
$detail = DB::table('restaurants')->find($restaurant_id);

<!-- View Code -->
<title>{{ $detail->name }}</title>
```

3. You can use `get()` as you did in your question but you need to access it as array with 0th index. I assumed that your query will retrieve only one record. It won't fail even if it retrieves multiple records but you will only first record in your view.

```
// Controller Code
$details = DB::table('restaurants')->where('id', $restaurant_id)->get();

<!-- View Code -->
<title>{{ $detail[0]->name }}</title>
```

There could be some more approaches but I used only these approaches so far.